# string subscript out of range c++ with fstream

Tags: c++, function, fstream

My code:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;
void insertionSort(int arrtosort[], int size);
const int SIZE = 10;
int main() {
    ofstream out;
    ifstream ingrades;
    unsigned seed = time(0);
    char doAgain = ' ';
    int id = 0;
    string grade = " ";
    int choice = 0;
    int fileid[SIZE];
    int numgrade[SIZE];
    int sum = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    int average = 0;
    int idx = 0;
    string letterGrade = " ";
    srand(seed);
    out.open("dataout.txt");

    while(counter <= 10) {
        out << (10000 + rand() % 99999);
        out << " ";
        out << (-1 + rand() % 10) << endl;
        //out<<" ";
        counter++;
    }
    out.close();

    ingrades.open("dataout.txt");
    for(idx = 0; idx < SIZE; idx++ ) {
        ingrades >> fileid[idx] >> numgrade[idx];
        sum = sum + numgrade[idx];
        counter++;
    }

    ingrades.close();
    average = sum / counter;
    out.open("dataout.txt");

    for( idx = 0; idx < SIZE; idx++ ) {
        if(numgrade[idx] == average || numgrade[idx] == average + 1) {
            out << fileid[idx] << " " << numgrade[idx] << " B";
            out << endl;
        } else if(numgrade[idx] == average + 2 || numgrade[idx] == average + 3) {
            out << fileid[idx] << " " << numgrade[idx] << " A-";
            out << endl;
        } else if(numgrade[idx] == average + 4 || numgrade[idx] >= 7 || numgrade[idx] == 10) {
            out << fileid[idx] << " " << numgrade[idx] << " A";
            out << endl;
        } else if(numgrade[idx] == average - 1) {
            out << fileid[idx] << " " << numgrade[idx] << " C";
            out << endl;
        } else if(numgrade[idx] == average - 2) {
            out << fileid[idx] << " " << numgrade[idx] << " F";
            out << endl;
        } else if (numgrade[idx] == -1) {
            out << fileid[idx] << " " << numgrade[idx] << " N/A";
            out << endl;
        }
    }
    out.close();

    ingrades.open("dataout.txt");
    for(idx = 0; idx < SIZE; idx++ ) {
        ingrades >> fileid[idx] >> numgrade[idx];
    }
    ingrades.close();

    do {
        cout << "\n" << right << setw(35) << "Teacher's Menu" << right << endl;
        cout << "---------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
        cout << "1) Sort the student list by id, and write it to your file" << endl;
        cout << "2) Search for a student by id and display the id," <<
             " numeric and letter grade to\n   the console" << endl;
        cout << "3) Search for students with a particular letter grade and display the results\n   to the console" << endl;
        cout << "4) Sort the student list by numeric grade and write it out to a file" << endl;
        cout << "5) Find the percentage of students for a particular letter grade" << endl;
        cout << "\n\tPlease enter which number option you wish to use: ";
        cin >> choice;
        ingrades.open("dataout.txt");
        switch(choice) {
        case 1:
            break;
        case 2:
            ingrades.clear();
            cout << "Enter in Student id: ";
            cin >> id;
            idx = 0;

            for ( idx = 0; idx <= SIZE; idx++ ) {
                ingrades >> fileid[idx] >> numgrade[idx] >> letterGrade[idx];
                if ( fileid[idx] == id && idx <= SIZE ) {
                    cout << fileid[idx] << " " << numgrade[idx] << " " << letterGrade[idx] << endl;
                    break;
                }
            }

            system("pause");
            break;
        case 3:
            /*  cout << "Enter in the Student letter grade: ";
                cin >> grade;
                for(idx = 0; idx < SIZE; idx++) {
                    if(grade == letterGrade[idx])
                        cout << fileid[idx] << " " << numgrade[idx] << " " << letterGrade[idx] << endl;
                }
                break;
                */
        case 4:
            break;
        case 5:
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Incorrect option" << endl;
        }
        cout << "Would you like to go back to the main menu y or n: " << endl;
        cin >> doAgain;
    } while(doAgain == 'y' || doAgain == 'Y');
    ingrades.close();
    //system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void insertionSort(int arrtosort[], int size) {
    int temp = arrtosort[0];
    for(int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
        temp = arrtosort[i];
        int j = 0;
        for(j = i; j > 0; j--)
            if(temp < arrtosort[j - 1])
                arrtosort[j] = arrtosort[j - 1];
            else break;
        arrtosort[j] =  temp;
    }
}
```

This was a school project but I failed the class but I am determined to finish the project and continue learning help is really needed I feel like I hit a brick wall.

I'm trying to read the IDs off a text it works up too the forth I'd then I get that error I want to understand why this is not working and how i can proceed with the rest of the program any and all help is greatly appreciated could also use help with applying my auto sort function the teacher gave us the loop but not sure how it works completely or how to correctly apply it.

The trouble I am having starts from line 127 and up giving me errors like string substring out of rang and difficulty comparing strings on case 3

Comment: 1) On what line do you get the error? 2) Your question doesn't say what the error is (although the title does). 3) `idx <= SIZE` probably should be `idx < SIZE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the lettergrade is not an array, hence the out of range fault. The correct code would be like this:

```
        for ( idx = 0; idx < SIZE; idx++ ) {
            ingrades >> fileid[idx] >> numgrade[idx] >> letterGrade;
            if ( fileid[idx] == id && idx <= SIZE ) {
                cout << fileid[idx] << " " << numgrade[idx] << " " << letterGrade << endl;
                break;
            }
        }
```

the insert sort also had a couple of bugs my version would look like this.

```
void insertionSort(int arrtosort[], int size) {
    int temp = arrtosort[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        temp = arrtosort[i];
        int j;
        for(j = i; j > 0; j--)
            if(temp < arrtosort[j - 1])
            {
                arrtosort[j] = arrtosort[j - 1];
                arrtosort[j-1] =  temp;
            }
            else break;
    }
}
```

Try to look at you old code and see what happens when an id is not smaller the its predecessor. And as @Dukeling mentioned all comparison with SIZE should be less and not less-equal.

One way of implementing the insert sort could be like this;

```
    case 4:
        insertionSort(fileid,SIZE);
        //fileid is now sorted
        for(int i=0; i< SIZE;++i)
        {
            ingrades.open("dataout.txt");
            for ( idx = 0; idx < SIZE; idx++ )
            {
                int id, t_grade;
                ingrades >> id >> t_grade >> letterGrade;
                //find the ith ID
                if ( fileid[i] == id)
                {
                    //and print it;
                    cout << id << " " << t_grade << " " << letterGrade << endl;
                    break;
                }
            }
            ingrades.close();
        }
        break;
```

this prints the ids and the belonging grades in order

Comment: First off I want to thank both of you because after 4 forums this is the only place that answered me back and I really appreciate it. Second could you explain why my array for theette

Comment: Letter* grades didnt work and how you worked the function cause I am a little confused by it

Comment: I actually see where i went wrong with my lettergrade if i had declared it as string letterGrade[SIZE] would that allow me to use it as an array for my case?

Comment: @AraEkmekjian That should probably work, try it out ;-)

Comment: Your help is awesome with that i can finally move on with my program i feel like for loops are still my weakest part but i greatly appreciate everything